# Spring Boot search data between two dates

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to search data between two date here is my repository

```
@Query("select mvt from Mouvements mvt where mvt.dateCompte between :x and :y")
public Page<Mouvements> getMouvementsByDate(@Param("x")LocalDate dateBefore, @Param("y")LocalDate dateAfter, Pageable pageable);
```

and here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/movementsByDate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Page<Mouvements> movementsByDate(
        @RequestParam(name= "dateBefore", defaultValue="")LocalDate dateBefore, 
        @RequestParam(name= "dateAfter", defaultValue="")LocalDate dateAfter, 
        @RequestParam(name= "page", defaultValue="0")int page, 
        @RequestParam(name= "size", defaultValue="5")int size){
    return mouvementsRepository.getMouvementsByDate(dateBefore, dateAfter, new PageRequest(page, size));
}
```

Now my problem is when I test this webservice with this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/movement/movementsByDate?dateBefore=27/11/2015&dateAfter=03/01/2019&page=0&size=9
```

I have this error

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam java.time.LocalDate] for value '27/11/2015'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [27/11/2015]",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best that you receive the parameters as String and then convert the String to LocalDate in your controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/movementsByDate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Page<Mouvements> movementsByDate(
        @RequestParam(name= "dateBefore", defaultValue="")String dateBeforeString, 
        @RequestParam(name= "dateAfter", defaultValue="")String dateAfterString, 
        @RequestParam(name= "page", defaultValue="0")int page, 
        @RequestParam(name= "size", defaultValue="5")int size){

        LocalDate dateBefore = LocalDate.parse(dateBeforeString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        LocalDate dateAfter = LocalDate.parse(dateAfterString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));

    return mouvementsRepository.getMouvementsByDate(dateBefore, dateAfter, new PageRequest(page, size));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot the default `LocalDate` conversion format is [`yyyy-MM-dd`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html#DATE) and you are using `27/11/2015` which is `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Either use [`@DateTimeFormat`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) to specify your own format for the request mapping paramters or use the default format in the request. Do note that `/` character should be encoded as `%2F` when it's part of the URL, your example is invalid so it would be easier to use standard `2015-11-27`.

Spring should support `Optional` mapping so below should work:

```
@RequestParam(name = "dateBefore")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)
Optional<LocalDate> dateBefore
```

Comment: i have the same error when i use the default format yyyy-MM-dd in the url `http://localhost:8080/api/movement/movementsByDate?dateBefore=2015-11-20&dateAfter=2019-01-03&page=0&size=9`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the format of the `LocalDate` globally:

```
@InitBinder
public void localDateBind(WebDataBinder binder) {
     binder.registerCustomEditor(LocalDate.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
          @Override
          public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            LocalDate.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE); //CUSTOM FORMAT
          }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/movementsByDate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Page<Mouvements> movementsByDate(
        @RequestParam(name= "dateBefore", defaultValue="") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate dateBefore, 
        @RequestParam(name= "dateAfter", defaultValue="") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate dateAfter, 
        @RequestParam(name= "page", defaultValue="0")int page, 
        @RequestParam(name= "size", defaultValue="5")int size){
    return mouvementsRepository.getMouvementsByDate(dateBefore, dateAfter, new PageRequest(page, size));
}
```

If you want to do this type of conversion globally, you can make use of a Spring Converter class

```
public class StringToLocalDateConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDate> {
    public LocalDateTime convert(String source) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE;
        return LocalDate.parse(source, formatter);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register this